# How to save events in Android & get reminders of events but without showing events to other Calendar Apps?

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, reminders

I have an app in which I am allowing the user to **schedule** future events and control volume settings during those times. So, I am allowing user to create events (with dates, times, and frequency).

I was thinking of using the Calendar API in Android but I do not want these "event times" to be visible to other calendar apps.

1. Can I use the Calendar APi - to save event times & get notifications AND also hide it from other apps?
2. Or Do I have to implement my own reminder functionality (like a Service already in the background which reads event info from my own sqllite db and changes volume settings accordingly)

Are there any other alternative approaches or libraries that can be of help there?

Comment: Is [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) not suitable for you?

Comment: I need to set a "duration" for the event also and change volume settings for that duration. But I guess I could embed the "duration" information in the Intent that i will use to create the Alarm? Hmmmm... let me look into it, thanks for the pointer. +1

Comment: Using services to 'schedule' events using timers for example is poor practice as there is a good chance that your service will be killed as Android performs its memory management. An alternative to using the Calendar API would be AlarmManager, but this will require a BroadcastReceiver to manage any timed operations.

Comment: @user1841702 - i dont intend to use Service to schedule events. The Service will be fired when the event time starts and end itself when the event time stops. During that even duration the service is going to manage the volume settings. the alarms will be scheduled from an activity, like they are supposed to.